# Rx JS await until all subscribers resolved promises

Tags: rxjs

I am making a game with rxjs.
When I update value on behaviour subject using the next method I cant await until all the subscribers played, for example finished their animations.

Is it possible to await until all subscribers played?

I have tried but wasn't able to find any info on that. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data.next("some data needed for animation");
```

somwhere

```
data.subscribe((response)=>{

     const allAnimationResponse = await await gsap.to(pixiSprite, {duration: 1, x: 100});

     if(allAnimationResponse){
     
            // you can access response and allAnimationResponse
            // execute next line
     }

})
```

Comment: What i want to do is 
`await data.next("some data needed for animation")`

and in separate class:

`data.subscribe(() => {
await until animation finished
})`

Comment: how animation runs ? I need to know it.  what is `await until animation finished` code wise ?

Comment: `await gsap.to(pixiSprite, {duration: 1, x: 100})`

Comment: So when I am calling
data.next I want to know whne all of the subscribers finished their animations

Comment: what does `gsap.to(pixiSprite, {duration: 1, x: 100})` return? promise  or observable or something else?

Comment: it returns promise

Comment: Now what I am thinking, it would be possible to pass promise resolver to observable together with data and subscriber would get that resolver and run it when animation finished. Is it a good solution?

Comment: See understand that I won't be able to understand what you are saying without looking at your code.  But sounds like it is doable.

Comment: Yeah, well, I am very thankfull for you help (: have a great day!